# What is a maximum offset height in a ball's structuring element?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, mathematical-morphology

I'm trying to use a closing morphology operation in MATLAB, `imclose(volume, SE)`, with a ball structuring element with a radius of 13 voxels.

The process to create a ball structuring element is like this:
`SE = offsetstrel('ball',r,h)`.

As stated in the [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/offsetstrel.html), `h` is the

> Maximum offset height, specified as a real scalar. of type double.

What is the maximum offset height?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The “maximum offset height” is the maximum value within the structuring element (the documentation calls these values “offset height”). For a ball, this is in the middle pixel (origin). It looks like the SE values are linearly stretched to obtain the chosen value in the middle. The outer edge of the ball is always at 0. Thus, in a sense, this value controls the aspect ratio of the ball.